# Dealing with parallel requests in React.JS / Redux ( Flux )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

***Scenario***

- 2 Container components rendered
- Each container is subscribed to the "Basket" piece of state. Within their componentDidUpdate they should go and re-fetch data from the pricing API and display the results ( i.e running totals with offers etc )

[Image of multiple containers all trying to fetch data @ same time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qquhX.png)

***Issue***

The issue is that a race condition will happen. When basket updates the flow looks something like this

**Component1** `compenentDidUpdate` is triggered due to basket update

- Check if `pricingDetails.isLoading` is `false`, if not fetch data
- Dispatch `fetchPricingData()` - this will set `pricingDetails.isLoading` to false

**Component2** `componentDidUpdate` is triggered

- Check if `pricingDetails.isLoading` is `false` ( IT is still is false at this point, as **Component2** subscription update to the `isLoading` state hasn't happened quick enough )
- Perform a second call to `fetchPricingData` - meaning now we've got 2 API calls on the go!

***Solution?***

Currently there seems a couple of ways I can think to tackle this, but none particularly elegantly

1) Delegate responsibility of fetching data to a higher level container where only a single instance of it will ever exist.

2) Have each container somehow use a "slave/master" setup, where only 1 initial instance is allowed to fetch data.

Comment: Reposted, because I messed up the english in the first try. JavaScript is single threaded. The first call will set isLoading true before the second call runs. if line 1 is `isLoading = true` and line 2 is `loadData();` then nothing will happen between those two lines.

Comment: @AndyJ this isn't true in the react world. Component2 has no guarantee that the subscription to the isLoading state happens BEFORE the componentDidUpdate is already fires and it's too late ( I've tested this with code myself ). I've update the ticket to make this cleared

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking the isLoading flag in the redux action? Rather than the component? https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/async Check out "src/actions/index.js" `fetchPostsIfNeeded` and "src/containers/app.js" `componentDidMount`.